# Automatic packages installer

Tags: software-installation

is there any method to install all packages with just one click !
included (*.deb) (*.tar.gz) (*.tar.gz2) (*.tgz)
cause i wanna install a lot of things and i got problems like hen installing Aircrack-NG
Python-Scapy
Python Qt4
Python
Subversion
Xterm
Reaver (for WPS Attacks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such command. Different packages are meant for different things. Also .tar.gz or .tar.bz2 (or .tgz, or .tar.xz, etc…) are not exactly packages. They are simply archive files, like a .zip file would be. They may or may not contain software.

The easiest way to install things, is to use Software Center to find the applications which are packaged in Ubuntu, and install them from there.